# Templating in ClojureScript

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, client-side-templating

I'd like to use ClojureScript to make a "single page" style web app. To that end, I need a client-side templating system. Does anyone have any experience and/or recommendations on which ClojureScript templating systems I should look into? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

you might have a look at [dommy](https://github.com/prismatic/dommy), a templating system written/used by Prismatic.

Answer (score 3):

I've found [crate](https://github.com/ibdknox/crate) to be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Having used both Crate and Dommy I can say that they are both very good. Crate is just an implementation of Hiccup from Clojure converted to Clojurescript for templating, so you will still need to use Domina to select elements. If you want a framework that handles both DOM selection AND templating then use Dommy

Answer (score 2):

I know three templating flavors for Clojurescript:

1. Dommy: Create and manipulate DOM nodes directly from cljs code.
2. Crate: Declare and manipulate cljs data (vectors,maps, etc.) which are then transformed into DOM nodes.
3. [Enfocus](https://github.com/ckirkendall/enfocus): Write HTML in HTML files, process them and transform them from cljs. It is a different way of thinking about templating, and it is based on the clj library Enlive.

There are libraries that produce React DOM nodes instead of normal DOM nodes but work in the same way as those mentioned above:

1. Any Cljs React wrapper, like Om or Reagent
2. Sablono
3. Kioo

I know you are only asking for templating and React comes with more than that, but if you need anything besides the most basic operations, I would recommend any React based approach.

Answer (score 1):

Since it hasn't been mentioned so far: I really like [Hoplon](http://hoplon.io/). It combines the following set of tools:

> - Custom HTML elements are regular functions and can be created and composed functionally with [HLisp](https://github.com/hoplon/hoplon/wiki/HLisp).
> - Spreadsheet-like dataflow with the [Javelin](https://github.com/hoplon/javelin) ClojureScript library. Intuitively model reactive behavior using cells and formulas.
> - Interact with the server with the [Castra](https://github.com/hoplon/castra) Clojure and ClojureScript library. Define functions on the server, call them from the client.

You can either use it as a full-stack solution or work with it on the client-side only. To give you an impression (taken from [GitHub](https://github.com/hoplon/hoplon#example)):

```clj
(page "index.html")

(defn my-list [& items]
  (div
    :class "my-list"
    (apply ul (map #(li (div :class "my-list-item" %)) items))))

(def clicks (cell 0))

(html
  (head
    (title "example page"))
  (body
    (h1 "Hello, Hoplon")

    (my-list
      (span "first thing")
      (span "second thing"))

    (p (text "You've clicked ~{clicks} times, so far."))
    (button :click #(swap! clicks inc) "click me")))
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answers you've already received, I would recommend that you check out systems based on [React](http://facebook.github.io/react/) such as [Om](https://github.com/swannodette/om), [Reagent](http://reagent-project.github.io) or [Quiescent](https://github.com/levand/quiescent). Of the three, my personal favourite is Reagent, but any of them would be an improvement over traditional DOM manipulation IMHO.